# MySQL 5.7.9 fulltext research in multiple tables with Sphinx on WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I I have to do a research in multiple MySQL tables for my internship.
In fact, I do this for a web phone directory. I have a form text input to enter the research.
I tried to use the MATCH/AGAINST syntax but it appears to be wrong.
My query is actually that one :

```
SELECT U_ID, 'users'
from users  
where match ([columns that I want to search in]) AGAINST ([The text inside my search field])

UNION

SELECT S_ID, 'service'
from service 
where match ([columns that I want to search in]) AGAINST ([The text inside my search field])
```

This problem is the following : With this type of search, I must send the variable in many MATCH so I can't have a relevant result (because of the multiple against elements). The perfect solution could be to replace the 'UNION' by an 'INTER' but It would be too easy.
I don't know if it will be usefull, but I use PDO to send my query with PhP

I tried to search solutions but I couldn't find one for me :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html 
[Using Full-Text Search in SQL Server 2008 across multiple tables, columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403630/using-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2008-across-multiple-tables-columns) 
[MySQL fulltext search on multiple tables with different fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167358/mysql-fulltext-search-on-multiple-tables-with-different-fields?rq=1)

Then I tried to use Sphinx but the documentation is complicated to me and I couldn't understand it (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html).

Can someone help me to find the query that I need or can you give me a link of a very clear and simple Sphinx tutorial on Windows (I have read the IBM one) ?

Edit :

I wanted to illustrate my problem with the set theory (inter mean intersection).
For example, when I type "John accounting department" in my form input, I want to display all users named John, but only if they belong to the accounting department.
With my actual search, I will have the id of all the departments named :  "John" or "accounting" or "department" and all the id for the people named "John" or accounting" or department".
That's my actual problem.

Comment: What is an [INTER] ? You also need to expand on [can't have a relevant result], its not actully clear what problem you facing. The example query should work, but you havent really explained **what** the problem is with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a ***materialized view*** would be the easiest way to solve this in MySQL.

They not strictly a feature of mysql (ie mysql cant maintain the view automatically, its not really a view) its a normal table, that just happens to be a **copy** of other table(s) data.

Can actually be created quite easily...

```
CREATE TABLE my_search_view (fulltext(U_Name,S_Name)) 
    SELECT U_ID, U_Name, S_ID, S_Name
    FROM user
    INNER JOIN service USING (S_ID);
```

(If you update the source tables, just delete the table, and recreate it! Although can use triggers if want a more dynamic solution, but depending size of data it possibly not worth the effort)

Now you can just run a simply query against this table (it has a full-text index)

```
SELECT *
FROM my_search_view
WHERE MATCH (U_Name,S_Name) AGAINST ('John accounting department')
```

Comment: I see the point of that query, but it doesn't work since you try to select S_ID and S_Name from the user table (I get a mysql error).

Comment: Well you of course have to tailor to what your columns are actually called. It's a JOIN so can use columns from **either** table joined.